# One view for all screen sizes

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Is there any way through which I can make my view work in all the screen sizes. I am currently facing issues that my code works fine in iphone12Pro however, it doesn't fit in the iPhone  touch-7th generation.
I have tried using all the internet helps however, when I use for example .padding(.horizontal, 70) and .padding(.vertical, 50), it works for one screen size, however, it won't in the other screen size. Can someone help me with the best way to write a code and get the same view in all the screens sizes. Thanks

```
GeometryReader {
}
Spacer()
VStack {}
```

Comment: If you use geometry reader you can compute relative sizes. But depending on what you screen look like try to remove all constants to see what are the differences between screen sizes. Use the Canvas to not run simulator after each change.

Answer (score 0):

Build UI that renders well independent of the view size.

For instance, instead of using large paddings to position your UI set max widths on your components and center-align them.